# Parsing JSON array in iOS 7

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I have this JSON code:

```
   [
  {
    "descrizione": "Risotto Giallo con Stinco",
    "prezzo": null
  },
  {
    "descrizione": "Orecchietta al ragu bolognese",
    "prezzo": null
  },
  {
    "descrizione": "Penne ai gamberi",
    "prezzo": null
  }
]
```

To print in a Text View, so that I wrote this code:

```
self.MenuGiorno.text = [self.MenuGiorno.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonArray1]];
```

Of course in this way I see in the Text View the complete code without parsing it.

How can I specify to print only "descrizione" and "prezzo"? Don't mind about Italian, this last two are the identifier I must use to fill the Text View. Someone has an idea?

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries. Get the dictionary you want from the array then get the values you want from the dictionary.

Comment: Can you code me a related example please?

Comment: Convert the JSON string into an `NSArray` with `NSJSONSerialization ` `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error`. Then access the items by key: `attar[0][@"keyName"]`

Comment: No. This is far too trivial. Do some research and searching. Start with the docs for `NSArray` and `NSDiitionary`.

Comment: @Zaph - look at the OP's code. They already have the array from the JSON.

Comment: Try writing some code, see my previous comment. If you have problems post the code and ask for help.

Comment: It's already an NSArray

Comment: Then just access the elements you need.

Comment: Note the title is: "Parsing JSON array", where is the JSON? ;-) My bad.

Comment: I tried with jsonArray1[@"descrizione"] but it doesnt' work...

Comment: `jsonArray1[0][@"descrizione"]` you are missing the the array index. The `[0]` accesses the first array item, the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jasonArray1` is an array of dictionaries. First you must access the array element, there is only one, the dictionary. Then access the dictionary item by key name.

```
NSString *str = jsonArray1[0][@"descrizione"];
```

or more verbosely:

```
NSArray *fistArrayElement = [jsonArray1 firstObject];
NSString *str = [fistArrayElement objectAtIndex:@"descrizione"];
```

Comment: By this way have I to insert in textview the firstArrayElement? Am I right?

Comment: I tried to make in this way:

`for (i=0;i<jsonArray1.count;i++){
            str1=jsonArray1[i][@"descrizione"];
            str2=jsonArray1[i][@"prezzo"];
            str1=[str1 stringByAppendingString:@" "];
            str1=[str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];

            self.MenuGiorno.text=[self.MenuGiorno.text stringByAppendingString:str1];
            

        }`


Although I gain thread killing...